# How to add more than 1 IP range in `-m iprange --src-range`?

Tags: iptables

I already has `-A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 110.174.0.0-110.174.255.255 -p tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT` in `iptables`.

When I want to accept another IP range `112.17.0.0-112.17.255.255`, I use `-A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 110.174.0.0-110.174.255.255 112.17.0.0-112.17.255.255 -p tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT`but iptables fail to start.

How to add more than 1 IP range in `-m iprange --src-range`?

Comment: Why not just have 2 iptables rules - one for each range?

Comment: I would go even further and suggest using `ipset` for that purpose.